# How to use reservoir states for readout and training?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection

I’m trying to make a Liquid State Machine, I have a spiking neural network as the liquid, and a feedforward neural network that should learn to map the reservoir’s states to the output.

I’ve read many articles, but I didn’t find much about how I give the reservoir’s states to the feedforward network’s inputs. One of my sources said that I should sum all the reservoir’s values and give it to all input units, but that would result in the inputs having all the same value.

Other articles said that the input units should be sensitive towards different features, but my project is recognizing handwriting and I have no idea what features I could extract from that. It only consists of values between 0 and 1, according to whether the pixel is filled or not.

I tried to map the liquid’s different layers to different input units of the feedforward network, but it also didn’t work. I didn’t really think it was a good idea, but I tried it just in case.

My question is: how do I give the reservoir's states to the feedforward network, so it could learn anything at all?

I also might have problems with the liquid itself too, since it doesn’t do anything, only fires its data randomly. Should it also change its structure according to the input data? (The articles usually say that it doesn’t have to react to the input, but I think it’s strange.)